# Why ActiveMQ doesn't and console still shows messages after deleting db-*.log files from KahaDB

Tags: activemq-classic

I am using KahaDB as a persistent storage to save message in ActiveMQ 5.16.4.

```xml
<persistenceAdapter>
    <kahaDB directory="${activemq.data}/kahadb"
            checkForCorruptJournalFiles="true"
            checksumJournalFiles="true"
            ignoreMissingJournalfiles="true"
    />
</persistenceAdapter>
```

I'm sending persistent messages and then while the broker is running I'm deleting the KahaDB log files (`db-1.log` in below picture) which are supposed to hold the queue's messages. However, but deleting the log file doesn't seems to do anything. In the ActiveMQ console I still see the persistent messages, and I can also send more messages which get picked up by connected consumer from Spring Boot apps. I thought deleting those log files will get rid of messages that are pending in queue or break ActiveMQ. Any idea why it isn't happening?

Inside KahaDB folder:
[image]

Comment: yes doing it while the broker is running and sending persistent messages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActiveMQ doesn't treat KahaDB like a SQL database where messages are stored and retrieved during runtime. Generally speaking, ActiveMQ keeps all of its messages *in memory* and it uses KahaDB is a *journal* to store messages which it will reload into memory if the broker fails or is restarted administratively. Deleting KahaDB's underlying data won't impact what is in the broker's memory, and it's not clear why you would ever want to do this in the first place.

If you want to remove the messages from a queue during runtime you can do so administratively via the web console. Deleting the KahaDB log files is **not** the recommended way to do this.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I was doing some research to see if i delete persistent storage(i use a disk space for this), will activemq still be functional. and you are right. i was reading https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/activemq-architecture-and-metrics/#memory-and-storage. This seems to describe more clearly. But what if the memory runs out and we dont have a persistent storage, what happens then?

Comment: I recommend you ask a new question about the use-case when memory runs out and you don't have any persistent storage.